# CSS Custom Cursor Image

Tags: css, cursor

I've been playing around with this - I want one image to show all the time as a pointer and anything clickable as a hand, I want to show a different image anywhere on my web page across multiple browsers.

```
html {
     cursor: url('../images/cursor/image.gif'), pointer;
}
```

this code works to display an image in my page outside of clickable elements (the detault pointer). I can't seem to figure out how to change the hand cursor on ANY clickable element (List item/link/etc)

My page has a lot of jquery elements.

IS there a simple solution to this?

Comment: As far as I know only links (`a` elements) have the `pointer` cursor by default. Wouldn’t simply something like `a{cursor: url(../images/cursor/pointer.gif),pointer;}` solve the issue?

Comment: Did you try`*{cursor:url('....');}` ?